# Accessing Github data in Jupyter Books

Tags: python, pandas, csv, github

Getting a tokenising error when I try to access a csv file in Jupyter Books. Had a look at some responses but none seem to help. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
url = "https://github.com/Kallikrates/bde_at2/blob/3875fd9b03b02b2772129acf2d8d83619971b2eb/2016Census_G01_NSW_LGA.csv"
insert_df = pd.read_csv(url, header=0, sep=',', quotechar='"')
insert_df.head()
```

ERROR:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-21-21c294baaa45> in <module>()
      1 url = "https://github.com/Kallikrates/bde_at2/blob/3875fd9b03b02b2772129acf2d8d83619971b2eb/2016Census_G01_NSW_LGA.csv"
----> 2 insert_df = pd.read_csv(url, header=0, sep=',', quotechar='"')
      3 insert_df.head()

3 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   2155     def read(self, nrows=None):
   2156         try:
-> 2157             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   2158         except StopIteration:
   2159             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 79, saw 2
```

Comment: try `insert_df = pd.read_html(url)` and result will be list, so your dataset will be `insert_df[0].head()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two options:

**1st:** read as html

```
url = "https://github.com/Kallikrates/bde_at2/blob/3875fd9b03b02b2772129acf2d8d83619971b2eb/2016Census_G01_NSW_LGA.csv"
insert_df = pd.read_html(url)
insert_df[0].head(2)
```

**2nd read as raw**, observe the URL,"raw" in it.

```
url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kallikrates/bde_at2/3875fd9b03b02b2772129acf2d8d83619971b2eb/2016Census_G01_NSW_LGA.csv"
insert_df_raw = pd.read_csv(url, header=0, sep=',', quotechar='"')
insert_df_raw.head(2)
```

output:
[image]

Comment: Amazing. Thanks @simpleApp!